# What kind of migration is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to setup a model based on a pre-built model that has the following code in the migration:

```
   def change
      create_table :friendships do |t|
         t.string :user_id, :friend_user_id
         t.string :status
       end
  end
```

I get the `t.string :status` part where a column is being created which will use a string. I don't understand the `t.string :user_id, :friend_user_id` part where there are two attributes on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line, two columns are being created named as `user_id` and `friend_user_id` having string data type. In the second line there is another column being created named `status` having string data type. So in migrations you can write all column names in one line which have the same data type. i.e. The migration can be written like this.

```
def change
  create_table :friendships do |t|
    t.string :user_id, :friend_user_id, :status
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a join table to show relationship. Actually `user_id` and `friend_user_id` all refer to `id` in users table.

Say my id is 10 and yours is 11. I regard you as a "good" friend. So in this table there is a record: 10, 11, "good". But you think me as a normal friend, so one more record: 11, 10, "normal"

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a declaration of two columns with similar attributes in the same line. It is similar to

```
t.string :user_id
t.string :friend_user_id
```

You can find the documentation for that in [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html) (look for "Short-hand examples")